# Nginx can't load /usr/share/nginx/html/ files are missing

Tags: javascript, docker, nginx, dockerfile, docker-build

I would like to dockerize and create a build process for a simple Vue.js application using Dockerfile. But, I get some errors when building from NGINX, it looks like the static build files of the project are missing. When I log in to `localhost:8080` - I get an empty page, and in the console the following messages:

> 2023/01/06 07:00:03 [error] 30#30: *1 open()
> "/usr/share/nginx/html/vue-ims/js/chunk-vendors.97986597.js" failed
> (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost,
> request: "GET /vue-ims/js/chunk-vendors.97986597.js HTTP/1.1", host:
> "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/"
>
> ...

I tried to access the /usr/share/nginx folder inside the container, but nothing was visible there. During the dockerfile build process, it should `COPY` all the necessary files to certain folders that should be accessible, but seems like nothing happened.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .env ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I also tried to build without the production stage as mentioned in comments, checked the /app/dist, /js/ folder inside the container and got the files there.

Comment: Have you tried removing your second stage and checking to see if `/app/dist/` exists and has the correct files?

Comment: @bassxzero
So, you mean only to run `FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .env ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build` ?

Comment: Yes. You might also want to add `CMD ["tail -f", "/dev/null"]` so that the container stays running long enough for you to check the /app/dist directory.

Comment: @bassxzero I checked, as you said, the app/dist directory and static files are present in it. Made a build without Nginx production stage.

Comment: Did you check the js directory to make sure the chunck-vendors file is also being created?

Comment: @bassxzero Yes, all files that are necessary is provided there

Comment: If the files exists in the correct location then it's probably a problem with your nginx config. You might need to supply a custom nginx config like this example. https://gist.github.com/wookets/0d196de017e74f8e7ee9001e5a9c89f4

Comment: How are you actually running the container?  If you `docker run --rm your-image ls /usr/share/nginx/html` (without editing the Dockerfile at all) are the files there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @bassxzero solved this problem.

nginx.conf:

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
  }
}
```